# ¿Por qué tengo este error con eslint?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

Acabo de configurar `eslint` y me sale este error :

> Error:missed comma between flow collection entries at line 11 "rules":{}

Este es el contenido de `.eslintrc`.

```
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
  },
  "extends": "airbnb"
  "rules": {
    "no-console": 0,
    "no-unused-vars": 1
  },
  "plugins": [
    "html",
    "markdown",
    "jsx-ally"
  ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Errores

Ten en cuenta que el mensaje de error dice:

> Error:missed comma between flow collection entries at line 11

Lo que traduciendo diria algo como:

> Error: Hay una coma perdida entre la coleccion de entradas en la linea 11

Aunque se pueden evidenciar otros errores en el objeto JSON.

#### Uno

```
"es6": true,
"browser": true, <- Esta coma NO debe ir aca
},
```

#### Dos

```
"extends": "airbnb" <- Falta una coma
```

#### Tres

```
"plugins": [ "html","markdown","jsx-ally" ]
}
} <- Estas cerrando DOS VECES el objeto de JSON
```

### Solucion

Podrias dejar tu objeto asi:

```
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true
  },
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "rules": {
    "no-console": 0,
    "no-unused-vars": 1
  },
  "plugins": [
    "html",
    "markdown",
    "jsx-ally"
  ]
}
```

> Nota: Si quieres verificar tu objeto JSON, puede usar una herramienta como [JSONEditorOnline](http://jsoneditoronline.org/)

Comment: ya hice los cambios y nada

Comment: Que error te esta arrojando ahora?

Comment: Error while running ESLint: Failed to load plugin jsx-ally: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-jsx-ally'.

Comment: Bueno, parecer ser que ya no es un error de sintaxis sino del modulo que no se puede encontrar

Comment: vale gracias reinstalare

Comment: En otra pregunta te respondieron que el plugin que debes instalar es `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y` y eso probablemente signifique que en tu `eslintrc` debas ponerlo como `jsx-a11y`